# Does Kubuntu have GPG keys?

Tags: kubuntu, security

Does a Kubuntu have a GPG keys to prove the authenticity of OS image?

I saw the Ubuntu have, but didn't see anything for [K]ubuntu.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, signed with the same key as the other Ubuntu releases.

E.g.

Download both the checksum files and the detached signature:

- http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/14.04.2/release/SHA256SUMS
- http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/14.04.2/release/SHA256SUMS.gpg

Then verify it against the preinstalled APT keyring which should have this key:

```
⟫ gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --verify SHA256SUMS.gpg SHA256SUMS

gpg: Signature made Thu 19 Feb 2015 23:32:54 CET using DSA key ID FBB75451
gpg: Good signature from "Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key <cdimage@ubuntu.com>"
```

Don't forget to actually verify the hashes.

```
⟫ sha256sum -c SHA256SUMS
[No such file or directory errors for files you didn't download]
...
kubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso: OK
```

Comment: These links are 404 in 2022 - are GPG signatures still available for current releases, and where?

Comment: @Bennypr0fane The concept remains the same, but just change the release in the URL. And you can even browse the files on that cdimage site. E.g.: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/22.04.1/release/ and find the `SHA256SUMS` `SHA256SUMS.gpg` files there.